# How can I see the result of the last psql query?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I executed a long-running Postgres query in the `psql` terminal.  It displayed the result, but I pressed `q` too soon, exiting out of the result and back to the prompt.

Is there any way for me to see the result again without rerunning the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've lost that output. Though the query is likely fairly "hot" atm as it was just requested (by you).

In the future though you can use the `\o [filename]` syntax of `psql` to save the output of the command locally, such that you don't run into this issue again.